# Does Adobe iOS packager work on linux?

Tags: linux, ant, air, package, flex4.6

We use ant command line script to build ios flex application via adt (flex 4.6 air 3.3).
Sample:

```
<java jar="${FLEX_HOME}/lib/adt.jar" fork="true">
            <arg value="-package"/>
            <arg value="-target"/>
            <arg value="ipa-ad-hoc"/>
            ...
```

Script works fine on Windows. But on linux I get:

```
 [java] unexpected failure: Functionality not supported on : Linux
 [java] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Functionality not supported on : Linux
 [java]     at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.<init>(AOTCompiler.java:218)
 [java]     at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.createIosBinary(IPAOutputStream.java
```

Should it work on linux or I did mistake in script?

Stan

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on linux as Adobe left support of Air for linux since 2.7.

It could work with wine by it's tricky.